# Privacy permissions not retained

Tags: macos, privacy

Running Monterey 12.4 but this has been happening since Catalina. When I restart into macOS from Boot Camp, I get a number of popups asking for various permissions for various apps. Typically, Full Disk Access or Accessibility in order to control the computer. All of these permissions have been previously granted. If I go into System Preferences>Privacy, the permission is often checked. If I enter my password, uncheck, and check the entry, the app is satisfied. If instead of trying to grant all the permissions, I simply restart into macOS again, most of the time, there are no popups and the apps have their appropriate permissions. I have tried resetting the TCC database and re-entering permissions, but the problem came back. I have not tried deleting the TCC database. I would rather not if I can get a "milder" solution.

Has anyone an idea if this is normal or a fix for when the permissions database needs regular repetitive configuration after changing the boot order?

Comment: I’ve had this extremely annoying issue for a long time, even before Catalina iirc. It could happen on any reboot regardless of Bootcamp. It’s become more intermittent recently and hasn’t been a problem on my last several reboots (M1 MBA, macOS Monterey).

Comment: To follow up on this, I've again tried resetting privacy settings using tccutil. I quit an app, then reset an individual app's settings, and then start the app again to re-enter settings. The same app prompted for settings the next time I restarted.

Comment: This happens very frequently and Apple just won't fix it.  Looks like to me like the Accessibility database just doesn't get loaded until way too late (after many apps have already launched).  Only fix is to log out and log back in and try 5 times until it works